# Pass URL parameter to AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app I'm [reading an URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1329116) which I'd like to pass to my Angular controller, which will then load a JSON file.

For example `index.html?id=1234` should make make the controller load `data/1234.json`

My current code results in an injector error:

```
var id = getUrlParam('id')

app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http, id) {
  $http.get("data/"+id+".json").then(function(res) {
      $scope.posts = res.data
  })
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @idlebery - Please share how you add $routeParams.id because I am getting erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$routeParams` is what you need.
Basicaly get your parameter like `$routeParams.id`

Additional information - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```js
var getParameterByName = (function(a) {
    if (a == "") return {};
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {
        var p=a[i].split('=', 2);
        if (p.length == 1)
            b[p[0]] = "";
        else
            b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
var id = getParameterByName["id"];
```